# Count number of cells satisfying a condition in pandas dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Hi I have following dataframe

```
Name Gender Age
ABC  M      21
C-DF F      24
```

I have to count the number of cells having a dash in them. I used the regular expression and wrote the code written below

```
df[df['Name'] == r'-+'].sum()
```

The output that I am getting is. I don't understand what mistake did I do or if I wrote the wrong command.

```
Name             0.0
Gender           0.0
Age              0.0
dtype: float64
```

Please help. Thanks.

Comment: The question has no relation to regex, I removed the tag. Note that when you use a regex, `-+` pattern will match 1 or more `-` chars.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I know that Wiktor. I used it because there are values in the set which have more than one dashes. :)

Comment: Yeah, but you wanted to just count a row that contains just 1 `-`. Unless you need to match any type of dashes, like in the `Pd` Unicode class, you can safely use `.contains('-')`

Comment: Ah, alright, I understand that. Yes, that's true. I wanted to count rows containing one or more dash :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`contains`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) for boolean mask with `sum` - `True`s are processes like `1`s:

```
print (df)
   Name Gender  Age
0  AB+C      M   21
1  C-DF      F   24

a = df['Name'].str.contains(r'-').sum()
print (a)
1
```